# Error closing ServerSocket after file transfer Java

Tags: java, file-transfer, serversocket

I have the code below When I do not have the close ServerSocket statement I get an error saying it is a resource leak but when I add the close statement Eclipse tells me the code is unreachable, How can I change the code to close the socket outside of the while statement?

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerPort);
    File incomingFile = new File("testfile.txt");

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting For File");
        Socket incomingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) incomingFile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(incomingFile));
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bis.close();
        OutputStream os = incomingSocket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        if (incomingSocket != null) {
            incomingSocket.close();
        }

    }
    if(serverSocket != null) {
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to prevent resource leaks is using `try..finally`

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
    try {
        File incomingFile = new File("testfile.txt");
        while (true) {
            // your code
        }
    } finally {
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

or using the `try-with-resources` construct like this

```
    try (serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort)) {
        File incomingFile = new File("testfile.txt");
        while (true) {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

The reason that code is unreachable is because your `while` loop is unterminated. Note also that `serverSocket` cannot be null at that point in the code because constructors must always result in a new instance unless an exception is thrown.